# Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- bundle.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-dom

I'm taking a tutorial to learn React JS, everything was fine, for days I could run an example, simple, carrying out a recommended basic configuration, plus a few more add-ons that I add to recognize the Javascript version.

After several days of no longer reviewing the project, but it is working correctly, when executing the command, I do not see any error, but it does not show anything in the browser, only multiple errors appear in the console of this one.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled reac and react-dom, and the problem still persists, try a new project cloning it from a friend, and it works normally, and it only copied the same structure of mine.

#### Issues

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> The above error occurred in one of your React components: Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

It should be noted that errors appear in the file `bundle.js`, which is used to store the generated code through `webpack`

[image: errores]

[image: tree]

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "prueba",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"node server.js\" \"webpack -w\" "
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {                
                test: /.jsx$/,
                use:{
                    loader:'babel-loader'
                },
                exclude: /node_module/
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

#### app.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>                
                <h1>Mi Aplicacion React Js</h1>
                <h3>Probando la exportacion</h3>
            </div>
        )       
    }
}
```

export default App;

#### index.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {App} from './components/app.jsx';

render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('appStart')
)
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Aprendiendo React</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="appStart"></div>
        <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### Console

```
C:\Users\PterPmntaM\CursoReactJS\React_Scaffold> npm run dev

> prueba@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\PterPmntaM\CursoReactJS\React_Scaffold
> concurrently "node server.js" "webpack -w"

[0] Iniciando servidor
[1]
[1] Webpack is watching the files...
[1]
[1] Hash: 5fd2ce10b3c1788b385b
[1] Version: webpack 3.10.0
[1] Time: 4878ms
[1]     Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
[1] bundle.js  729 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
[1]   [14] ./src/index.jsx 381 bytes {0} [built]
[1]     + 27 hidden modules
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In app.jsx, the component is exported like so:

```
export default App;
```

But it's being imported like so:

```
import {App} from './components/app.jsx';
```

The code fails because the `App` export doesn't exist from app.jsx, and comes up `undefined` as the error suggests. It's being exported as `default` instead.

This is the correct way to import it:

```
// The recommended way
import App from './components/app.jsx';

// The alternative way, to better illustrate what's going on
import { default as App } from './components/app.jsx';
```

Here's a good overview for ES modules: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales I'm able to reproduce the problem and the solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/939315151w

Comment: @kingdaro here the [repo react scaffold](https://github.com/PterPmnta/React-Scaffold-2)

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Your webpack config is putting the bundle at `js/bundle.js`, but your app is being served from `public/js/bundle.js` instead. You need to update your webpack config to build into `public/js/bundle.js` instead.

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('public/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },